# JavaScript Beacon Web API in Safari

Tags: javascript, web, safari

I have a javascript basted web app that is using the Beacon Web API, `Navigator.SendBeacon()`, for sending a POST of log data when leaving a page view.

The issue now is that function is not supported in Safari (Info: https://caniuse.com/#search=beacon).

Is there something else that could work in safari and have a similar behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: HI, i am also facing this issue, Can any one help to me. Thanks

Comment: FYI it has been implement on Safari too, so now works in all major browsers!

Answer (score 1):

Use a ***polyfill*** (it falls back to XHR calls)

Here - **https://github.com/miguelmota/Navigator.sendBeacon**

Comment: On MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon#Description) it states that "user agents typically ignore asynchronous XMLHttpRequests made in an unload handler", so will this polyfill work on Safari iOS?